# Software thinks it is already installed, but isnt?

Tags: windows-7, installation, windows-registry, uninstall

I have a game which I would like to install but whenever I insert the CD/mount the image, when the menu pops up it shows "Play" rather than "Install". The Control Panel does not show the software listed under installed programs.

I think this is because of a previous installation which didn't complete correctly.

This is on Windows 7 64-bit. I do not know much about software installation. Would somebody be able to point me to which parts of the registry I should delete? I am assuming there is something in the registry making it think the game is installed? I just need to know the locations I can search for something resembling the game and delete them.

Comment: Why don't you just manually run the setup executable?

Comment: I wouldn't go off deleting things in the registry.  There are actually tools that can uninstall partially installed (or incorrectly installed) software.  Use one of them instead.

Comment: @rrirower but how can the tool detect what to delete if the Control Panel isn't even aware of it?

Comment: These "tools" can scrape the registry looking for what the system thinks is installed.  It's safer than you guessing at what should be removed.

Comment: fyi, knowing about the registry certainly makes it sound like you know at least a little about software installation and computers in general. What game are you trying to install specifically?

Comment: knowing the game would help.

Comment: @Keltari Command & Conquer generals. When I try to run from the desktop the game just freezes and then the process just dies.

Answer (score 1):

I would be comfortable removing a couple of things from the registry on this.

- regedit.msc
- HKLM\software\yourProgram - delete
- HKCU\software\yourProgram - delete
- verify that there is no directory for the program in Program Files x64 and x86
- if there are delete those directories.
- if you cannot delete them because they are in use, reboot in safe mode and delete it.

Alternatively, REVO uninstaller does a good job if it can detect the program.